# Mosquitto - subscribe to one broker and push to another using C

Tags: c, mqtt, iot, libmosquitto

Is it possible and if so how to archive it that one application using libmosquitto get messages from one broker and publish it to another?

[image: Schematics]

Its pretty simple to just change topic in mosquito_publish function, but set of broker takes place in

```
mosquitto_connect(mosq, "localhost",1883 , 60);
```

Running mosquitto_connet second time
e.g.

```
 mosquitto_connect(mosq, "mqtt.example.io",1883 , 60);
```

ends up connecting to last one.

I tried to create two mosquitto structs but I dont know how to inform second one about message form subbed channel in order to get info from it, change it and push to proper broker.

Comment: of course the other question here is why you can't just bridge the 2 brokers, instead of using a client in the middle?

Comment: I have to modify content of messages to publish based on messages from first one broker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do the job (I've not tested it though). You'll have to add error checking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mosquitto.h>


void on_connect1(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *obj, int result)
{
    int rc = MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS;

    if(!result){
        mosquitto_subscribe(mosq, NULL, "/v1/topic1", 0);
    }else{
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mosquitto_connack_string(result));
    }
}

void on_message1(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *obj, const struct mosquitto_message *message)
{
    struct mosquitto *mosq2 = (struct mosquitto *)obj;

    mosquitto_publish(mosq, NULL, "/v1/topic2", message->payloadlen, message->payload, message->qos, message->retain);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct mosquitto *mosq1, *mosq2;

    mosquitto_lib_init();

    mosq2 = mosquitto_new(NULL, true, NULL);
    mosq1 = mosquitto_new(NULL, true, mosq2);

    mosquitto_connect_callback_set(mosq1, on_connect1);
    mosquitto_message_callback_set(mosq1, on_message1);

    mosquitto_connect(mosq2, "mqtt.example.io", 1883, 60);
    mosquitto_connect(mosq1, "localhost", 1883, 60);

    mosquitto_loop_start(mosq2);
    mosquitto_loop_forever(mosq1, -1, 1);

    mosquitto_destroy(mosq1);
    mosquitto_destroy(mosq2);

    mosquitto_lib_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already managed that problem, but thanks to your answer I know  how to use third mosquitto_new arg.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

You need two totally separate instances of client. Which means two separate instances the `mosquitto` structure returned by the `mosquitto_new()` function. One for each broker.

At the moment you are re-using the same structure so it is only holding the details of the last call to `mosquitto_connect()`

Answer (score 0):

This command line using mosquitto can do the job:

```
mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t '#'  | {  while [ 1 -lt 2 ] ;   do   read message ;   if [[ "$message" != "$prev_message" ]]; then  mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t "tenewtest" -m "$message" ; prev_message=$message ; fi ;    done ;  }
```

Comment: You missed the requirement to modify the message on the way through the middle (in the comments under the question)

Comment: Yes, it is just a pass through. The publish can be done to a different server. You can also change the message after the read.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to forward the messages, then there is a 'bridge' functionality in mosquitto broker. It makes it easier through configuration. It has a feature where you can specify the topics you want to forward & also authentication options. It is quite feature rich.